# Content outside table, not in it?

Tags: jquery, html

Why is this `.html()` function in jQuery placing the hyperlink with `post.username` under the table, not inside it?

code:

```
.html('<table width="138" height="24" border="0"><tr><td width="280" class="style3"><a href="../profile.php?user=' + post.username + '" class="post-title"></td></tr></table>' + post.username + '</a><p class="item-content">' + post.item_content + '<br /></p>')
.click(function() {
    window.location = postURL;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because you're not following proper HTML formatting? Your anchor isn't closed inside the table, it's closed outside. Your insert looks like:

```
<table width="138" height="24" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="280" class="style3">
      <a href="../profile.php?user=' + post.username + '" class="post-title">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
' + post.username + '</a> <!-- Shouldn't this be inside the table? -->
<!-- And this is fine below the table (presumably) if you want it there -->
<p class="item-content">' + post.item_content + '<br /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `<a>` tag is not closed. You have wrong nesting of elements: the tag is opened inside a `<td>` and closed outside. Besides I would recommend you the following:

```
.html(
    $('<table/>', {
        width: '138px',
        height: '24px',
        border: '0',
        html: $('<tr/>', {
            html: $('<td/>', {
                width: '280px',
                class: 'style3',
                html: $('<a/>', {
                    class: 'post-title',
                    href: '../profile.php?user=' + encodeURIComponent(post.username),
                    text: post.username
                })
            })
        })
    })
).append(
    $('<p/>', {
        class: 'item-content',
        value: post.item_content
    })
).click(function() {
    window.location = postURL;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it IS outside the table. Your HTML reformatted:

```
<table width="138" height="24" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="280" class="style3">
      <a href="../profile.php?user=' + post.username + '" class="post-title">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- End of the table here -->
post.username</a>
<p class="item-content">
  post.item_content<br />
</p>
```

You probably want to put all the content inside the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you've closed the a tag after the table one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'r closing the table before you close the anchor

```
.html('<table width="138" height="24" border="0"><tr><td width="280" class="style3"><a href="../profile.php?user=' + post.username + '" class="post-title">' + post.username + '</a></td></tr></table><p class="item-content">' + post.item_content + '<br /></p>')
```